# 2 Way TLS for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication, ssl, ssis, certificate

How do I setup 2-way TLS/SSL certificate authentication between SQL Server 2008 R2 SSIS and a web service? I think this is called "client certificate authentication".

Information Security requires that we have 2-way rather than just 1-way authentication.